# How to set this css only works for specified class?

Tags: css

Given the following markup:

```
<div class="my_class"></div>
```

and and the following css:

```
.sidebar .nav { width: 95%; }
.sidebar-nav{ left: -200px; }
.sidebar-nav.active{ left: 0; }
```

How can I make the above styles apply *only* for children on the `my-class` class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is your `my_class` getting the styles from `sidebar`?

Comment: yes of course that css is running on my_class

Comment: Not sure what you mean + 1. In your css code, you can just do something like .my_class {width: 95%;} ?

Comment: There is no correlation between the example HTML and the example CSS. you assign `.my_class` whatever rules you want, and if you want to add `.my_class` to the existing CSS, just add `, .my_class` to the rule (then it will affect both the existing classes, and your new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my understanding that you want the following css to **only apply to** children of `.my_class`.

If so, please change your css to this:

```
.my-class .sidebar .nav { width: 95%; }
.my-class .sidebar-nav{ left: -200px; }
.my-class .sidebar-nav.active{ left: 0; }
```

Note that if you have any `sidebar` or `sidebar-nav` **outside** your `my-class` they won't be getting the above styles.

Check out [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on MDN.

Answer (score 3):

```
.my-class .sidebar .nav { width: 95%; }
.my-class .sidebar-nav{ left: -200px; }
.my-class .sidebar-nav.active{ left: 0; }
```